# Making Changes to Installed Packages

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to improve a package written in python . The package is already installed in the system. All the source files are also present . I want to create a copy of the package source so that i can make all the changes to the copy and test so that i do not make any change to the installed package . Is there a way for me to tell python to pick my copy of code instead of the Installed version whenever a file tries to import the package , so that i can test the new code in the copy ? I'm a noob with respect to python , so please do elaborate the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's multiple ways to do it, but setting up [virtual env](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) would allow you two have two distinct environments that you can switch between.

Comment: But i've too many dependencies for this package. I'll have to set up all this in the virtual env also rite ? The package is residing in the home folder, not in a usual Python library folder so there should be someway for me to make it point to a different folder is it not ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make change in the code; better will be; download its source code first; apply the changes; modify the `setup.py` file or make new one; give it a new name.. . i mean do not change directly in the installed version; do them separately .. .or do whatever you like
but before doing all this;  **study the license agreements present in the original source by its author ; and this must be done carefully when you want to distribute your copy to others**

Comment: The License is NewBSD License . So changing it wouldn't be of any problem

Comment: then search this term in google; for example i got this explanation from google search: 
http://pthree.org/2007/08/08/bsd-license-explained-in-layman-terms/